# SQL Where in for Many to Many Join Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following (moderately epic query) which I have been writing

```
Select * 
from 
    (Select 
         Salutation, 
         FirstName, LastName, FullName, 
         PhotoUrl, CountryCode, Email,  Birthday, 
         Gender, HomePhone, M.MemberId, IDType, JoinDate, 
         HomeLocation, HomeLocationId, 
         Region.Name as RegionName, 
         M.MembershipId, 
         coalesce(case 
                     when Package.PackageIsReoccuring = 1 then 'Recurring' 
                     when Package.PackageIsSession = 1 then 'Paid In Full' 
                     when membership.TotalPrice = 0 then 'Free' 
                     when Package.PackagePayInFull = 1 then 'Paid In Full' 
                  end, 'N/A') as PackageTerm,
        coalesce(PackageType.Name, 'N/A') as PackageType,
        coalesce(membershipstate.name, 'N/A') as MembershipState,
        MembershipStartDate = 
           case 
              when membership.StartDate IS NULL 
                 then '' 
                 else CONVERT(varchar(50),membership.StartDate) 
           end,
       MembershipEndDate = 
           case 
              when membership.EndDate IS NULL 
                 then '' 
                 else CONVERT(varchar(50),membership.EndDate) 
           end,
       Region.Id as RegionId
   from  
       (select
            AspNetUsers.Salutation,
            AspNetUsers.FirstName, AspNetUsers.LastName,
            CONCAT (AspNetUsers.FirstName, ' ', AspNetUsers.LastName) as FullName,  
            AspNetUsers.PhotoUrl, AspNetUsers.CountryCode, AspNetUsers.Email,
            AspNetUsers.Birthday, AspNetUsers.Gender, 
            AspNetUsers.HomePhone as HomePhone,
            Member.Id as MemberId, Member.IDType, Member.JoinDate,
            HomeLocation.Name as HomeLocation,
            HomeLocation.Id as HomeLocationId,
            (case when (select top 1 id from membership where membership.memberid = Member.id and (membership.membershipstateid = 1 or membership.membershipstateid = 6)) IS NULL Then (select top 1 id from membership where membership.memberid = Member.id order by membership.enddate desc) ELSE (select top 1 id from membership where membership.memberid = Member.id and (membership.membershipstateid = 1 or membership.membershipstateid = 6)) END) as MembershipId
        from
            AspNetUsers
        join 
            Member on AspNetUsers.id = Member.aspnetuserid
        join 
            Location as HomeLocation on Member.HomeLocationId = HomeLocation.id) as M
   left join 
       Membership on M.MembershipId = Membership.Id
   left join 
       Package on Membership.packageid = Package.Id
   left join 
       PackageType on Package.packagetypeid = PackageType.Id
   left join 
       MembershipState on Membership.membershipstateid = MembershipState.Id
   left join 
       Region on Membership.RegionId = Region.Id) as Result
order by 
    Result.LastName desc
```

I have a final join table which I want to use which is a many-to-many relationship on Region. Region has a Join Table (RegionLocations) which is a join between Region and Locations.

With my query below I would like to get all results where the HomeLocationId = 2 OR he has a LocationId (from RegionLocations) which also contains 2. The RegionId is a nullable value and isn't always populated.

How can I get this?  Do I need to return values into a CSV?  This final hurdle is a battle..

Thanks

Comment: why not use a subquery there as well?

Comment: I am not sure where to add the subquery...i basically need to get all members where their homelocationid is 2 or they have a regionlocation which is 2 as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend this:

```
left join 
    Region on Membership.RegionId = Region.Id) as Result
```

to this:

```
left join 
    Region on Membership.RegionId = Region.Id
where M.HomeLocationId = 2 
   or Region.Id in (select RegionId from RegionLocation where LocationId = 2)
) as Result
```

#### Some other remarks about your query:

The fields `MembershipStartDate` and `MembershipEndDate` can be evaluated more concisely as:

```
COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(50),membership.StartDate), '') as MembershipStartDate,
COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(50),membership.EndDate), '') as MembershipEndDate,
```

The inner field `MembershipId` is defined with three sub-queries in a `case when`, which can be shortened to just one query. It uses `in` instead of an `or` condition, and puts it in the `order by` clause in a way that gets the priority right:

```
        (select    top 1 id 
         from      membership 
         where     membership.memberid = Member.id 
         order by  case when membership.membershipstateid in (1,6) then 0 else 1 end,
                   membership.enddate desc
        ) as MembershipId
```

Finally, if you just have an outer query that performs a `select * from (...) order by`, then why not skip that outer query and perform that `order by` on the inner query direcly?

Comment: Does this take into consideration if the regionid is null and are my left joins vs joins correct?  i never know if its right or not...thanks for your help thus far however!

Comment: If `Region.Id` is `null` then the second condition in the `where` clause will be false, so then all depends on the first condition: `M.HomeLocationId = 2`. If that fails, then it is a no-match.

Comment: Your joins seems OK. Of course, I don't know all the ins and outs of your data, and what you expect in each case (there are many cases).

Comment: Ok thanks...i think i need to give my data a really good check over...im getting some inconsistencies